# How and when should I identify my specific research interests?

Tags: research-process, research-topic

I am a Computer Science graduate, who is passionate about Computer Science and various topics and want to explore them in and out.

I am interested in research but I cannot refine my interests to a particular topic. It is possibly because I did not get a chance to play with various stuffs and do various projects. So how should I refine my interests to a particular topic?Is it too early to think about it,that is should I wait for getting a Masters or am I right to think about it currently?

Comment: *Is it too early[...].* -- The sooner the better.

Comment: Since you haven't really specified how far you hope to go, my impression is that in most places it is okay (not great, but not terrible) to be as vague as "I really like graphics and algorithms" upon entry to the master's, but by the time you apply for a phd, you should be able to identify specific areas in a broader field that you think you could contribute to.

Comment: @Tim,can I do anything to refine my interests or explore my interests more?

Comment: @Trylks,any nice ideas to check my interests in a field?Can you suggest some sample techniques?

Comment: @user1369975 try to picture yourself getting a deeper and deeper knowledge about those topics for the rest of your life, if some of them don't seem unbearably boring then try to find 1) what do they have in common, 2) whether your expectations and reality are related (in literature and state of the art) and 3) the economic interest (opportunities, business models, how interested the markets are) to see respectively whether it is 1) interesting and personally viable, 2) technically possible and 3) economically acceptable.

Answer (score 6):

You are an undergrad now, so that means you have neither experience nor plenty of free time. But this doesn't mean you can't give it a shot: read up about research, and find interesting projects to do. Aim for something small, that you can, for example, accomplish in one year. The next year, try something different. I'd probably focus on topics that are not exactly covered in your curriculum, as those you are going to learn anyway.

I studied Physics, but on the side I experimented with computer simulations, to later go to image and video processing, analysis of experimental spectra, and complex networks (graph theory). All this taught me tools and ideas that I am now using, in a completely different field (Bioinformatics).

The truth is, before I started looking for a PhD, I didn't even considered Bioinformatics as an option, but I saw one offer, looked appealing, and decided it was exactly what I wanted to do. How is everything I did helping me? For example:

- I have to compare some pieces of data. Comparing them pairwise is simple, so I remembered networks, and designed a robust way of combining the comparison into a global measurement. As a plus, I knew already of a good library, and how to use it so I could start coding my ideas right away.
- Now I have a matrix, and I have to dig out some patterns (with lots of gaps). From my time doing image processing I remember reading about the Hough transform, and it turns out it looks a promising start point. But I also remembered when I was analysing spectra that the output is quite complex, so I will keep in mind the caveats.

The bottom line is that you don't have to start now in what you want to do. In fact, you will be a more efficient researcher if you know many different things, as you never know where you are going to end up. All this, of course, keeping an eye on your official studies.

Comment: ,sorry for the mistake.I mentioned that I am an undergraduate student but I am a graduate now.

Comment: @user1369975 what are you studying? Master's? Anyway, you can always do things on the side.

Comment: ,nope I have got placed in a company so I will be starting my job soon

Comment: @user1369975 that changes completely the situation. How do you plan to do research? In your spare time? As a part of your employment? Do you want to pursue a PhD in the future?

Comment: ,yes in my spare time.